# How to download a pdf that is already made in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

How do I place a `.pdf` into my assets and then have a view's `button` tag link to it so when clicked it downloads the pdf?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score -1):

Generally, if this is a static asset, you'd place it in the `public` folder. Then it will be available as `/filename.pdf`.